# How to return MaterialButton default border color?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button

I have two buttons, and i want to realize blue border on pressed one. When button pressed, it't border become blue, border of another button return to default.

I can't return default border correct. I write function, but is works wrong.

My button(second is the same with another id and text):

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_schemes_1"
            style="@style/Buttons.Schemes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/schemes_1"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_schemes_1" />
```

Style has nothing interesting:

```
<style name="Buttons.Schemes" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
        <!--android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"-->
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:letterSpacing">0</item>
        <item name="iconTint">@null</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

My last realization was about to find and remember default border value before first click happens, so at the first i write:

```
private var defaultColor: Int = 0
```

Then

```
defaultColor = btn_schemes_1.strokeColor.defaultColor
```

And function, called when one of button clicked:

```
  private fun setButtonsBorder(buttonNumber: Int) {
        when (buttonNumber) {
            1 -> {
                btn_schemes_1.strokeColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE)
                btn_schemes_1.strokeWidth = 2

                btn_schemes_2.strokeColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(defaultColor)
                btn_schemes_2.strokeWidth = 1
            }
            2 -> {
                btn_schemes_1.strokeColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(defaultColor)
                btn_schemes_1.strokeWidth = 1

                btn_schemes_2.strokeColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE)
                btn_schemes_2.strokeWidth = 2
            }
        }
    }
```

But this failed too, because default color not "those" default at fact. When i set it, i found it's just `colorPrimary`.

How can i find this default color or write method to retutn border color to default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i get it myself.

After goes deeper i call it before button clicked:

```
Timber.e(btn_schemes_1.strokeColor.toString())
```

And get:

```
ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=1073742848mStateSpecs=[[16842912], [-16842912]]mColors=[-16743049, 520093696]mDefaultColor=-16743049}
```

So 520093696 is my color. Google says it `black12 constant`, presented by `0x1F000000`

And after

`private var defaultColor: Int = 0x1F000000`

All works.